# Русские литеры в Java

Tags: windows, cmd, java

Я пока что начинающий программист и компилирую всё через командную строку. Я никак не могу понять, почему когда я хочу вывести на экран русский текст, java выводит на экран какие-то непонятные символы. Подскажите, как это исправить. В гугле чёткого ответа не нашел. И прошу перейти на IDE не предлагать (рано мне ещё).

Comment: Наверное самым правильным шагом будет переход с виды в линукс.

Comment: Если не хотите лепить костылей, то, действительно, переход на линукс - отличное решение.

Comment: Неет ребята, я Гейтса не предам))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я, наверное, очень злой и хочу, чтобы [[@Vikkingg](/users/2879/vikkingg)](/users/2879/vikkingg) продолжал мучить Гейтса и себя работой в консоли. Посему предложу три решения проблемы:

1. Менять кодовую страницу в консоли. Дело в том, что есть в винде вещица под названием `chcp.com` она кодовую страницу показать может и сменить. Так что вы можете либо в нужный момент набрать `chcp 1251`, либо сделать батник/ярлык примерно такого содержания: `cmd /k chcp 1251 1>nul`.
2. Можно вбить дефолтную кодировку консоли сразу в реестр, общесистемно. Идем и правим в ветке `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\` значение `CodePage` на 1251.
3. Можно отказаться от использования архаичного `cmd.exe` и перейти на вкусный *PowerShell* с поддержкой `utf-8` и всеми его плюшками.

---

**UPD0.**
Пока жаловался на парсер, в голову пришли еще три запасных способа:

1. В реестре в ветке `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` запилить параметр `AutoRun` со значением... все тем же `chcp 1251 1>nul`. При открытии консоли  будет выполняться смена кодовой страницы.
2. Раз мы говорим о Java, передавать при запуске `java.exe` параметр `-Dfile.encoding=Cp866`. То есть не консоль подгонять под нормальную кодовую страницу, а JVM под ненормальную. Правда в чем-то серьезнее хэллоуворлдов можно словить проблемы с кодировкой в других местах. Например, при подключении к БД или записи в файл (если она явно не будет указываться).
3. Способ несколько суров. Странно, что он пришел мне в голову последним, т.к. именно им пользуюсь я сам. Использовать консоль *Cygwin*-a или *MinGW*. Последняя, кстати, идет в комплекте с git-ом под винду (`msysgit`), так что если захотите освоить или уже пользуетесь git-ом в консоли, этот вариант может оказаться удобным. И не нужно переключать мозг, если попутно приходится работать с линуксовыми серверами: весь основной инструментарий тот же.

Как видите, есть из чего выбрать, а в IDE кнопки тыкать вы всегда успеете научиться.

Comment: Чуднó. @Хэшкод, парсер markdown-а несколько перебдел и решил, что chcp.com - это сайт. Не хотелось бы людей смущать, может не парсить ссылки в моноширинных фрагментах текста?

---
Создал [вопрос на Мете](http://meta.hashcode.ru/questions/227/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: Консоль от Cygwin или MinGW (или MSYS) это хорошее решение. 

Первый шаг от Гейтса в правильную сторону.

Comment: Ну нафиг, я с вашим powesrhell'ом задолбался!Даже cd не работает ппц какой - то!

Answer (score 6):

Зависит от того в какой кодировке вы там пишете по русски. Консоль Windows поддерживает по традиции кодовую страницу CP-866 (или я отстал?), а вы скорее всего пишете в нотепаде под CP-1251 - оттуда и кракозябры.

Перейдите под IDE и не мучайте Гейтса.